# IE error in timeout jquery

Tags: jquery, django

My coding is

```
<div align='center'>
    <ul id="message" >
        {% for message in messages %}
            <ul{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{message}}</ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul></div>
```

and

```
setTimeout( function() {
        jQuery('#message').hide();
    }, 5000 );
```

It fades the message after 5 seconds in chrome and firefox not in IE. Anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you need nested `<ul>`? Fix `ul` to `li` inside your loop.

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{message}}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

You variant is semantic invalid and IE probably doesn't understand it well. [Check your page](http://validator.w3.org/) to satisfy HTML/(X)HTML standards.

Comment: yes, Is there any problem by using like this in IE?. Iam getting the timeout msg in Chrome.In IE only this problem is coming...

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember well, and I cannot test this because amb using linux, but in IE i think that it would be something like that (it's ugly, but works)

```
setTimeout( "(function() {jQuery('#message').hide();})()", 5000 );
```